# How to add additional attribute according to the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML Code

```
<div id="ccc_new_val_hdn">
    <span>9</span>
    <span>,</span>
    <span> </span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>1</span>
</div>
```

I need to convert comma and space like this

```
<span class='comma'>,</span>
```

and space to

```
<span class='space'> </span>
```

I tried :contains() and find(), but i cannot get the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate and set classes.

```
$('#ccc_new_val_hdn span').each(function() {
    if($(this).html() == ','){
        $(this).addClass('comma');
    }
    if($(this).html() == ' '){
        $(this).addClass('space');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/igaraq

Answer (score 0):

You can just select all the spans inside the div and trim and then check the values, after that you can just set which class you want to apply.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ccc_new_val_hdn span').each(function(){
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        if(text === ',')
            $(this).addClass('comma')
        else if(text === "")
            $(this).addClass('space');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively `.text()` would suffice

```
$('#ccc_new_val_hdn span').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == ','){
        $(this).addClass('comma');
    }
    if($(this).text() == ' '){
        $(this).addClass('space');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers may behave differently when you have an element that contains a single whitespace character. Safari, for instance, simply removes it on parsing while Firefox preserves it.

jQuery's `:contains` filter may not be very useful as it does a search anywhere in the element's text content, but it looks like you want to do an exact search. The problem with `:contains` is that when searching for an element with just a comma, it will match all these:

```
<span>,</span>
<span>hello, world</span>
<span> , </span>
```

The second, and third elements will match both a comma and a space.

Here's a custom jQuery filter that is similar to `:contains`, but does an exact text match instead.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].hasText = function(element, index, meta) {
    var textToSearch = meta[3];
    return $(element).text() == textToSearch;
};
```

Use it as `:hasTexT(..)`. Here's an example of how to select elements by their text content and change their CSS class.

```
$(':hasText(,)').addClass('comma');
$(':hasText( )').addClass('space');
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yAQMe/1/). Try it in Firefox. Other browsers *may* eat up the single whitespace.