# JQuery and XML: content-based selection

Tags: jquery, xml

Which selector is better if I want to select some object basing on their .text()?

Eg. put that I have:

```
<tag>1</tag>
<tag>2</tag>
<tag>3</tag>
<tag>3</tag>
```

and I want to select only the objects with text='3'. How can I? Thanks. 
Lorenzo

Comment: Checkout the `hasText` filter in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8876538/165737) from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml='<sometag><tag>1</tag><tag>2</tag><tag>3</tag><tag>3</tag></sometag>';
    xml=$.parseXML(xml);
    $(xml).find("tag:contains(3)").each(function(index){
         //do what ever you like
      });
```

Comment: i am aware of the :contains selector, but with it I also get tags containing 3, like 33333, abc123 etc.

Answer (score 0):

in that case

```
var xml='<sometag><tag>1</tag><tag>2</tag><tag>3</tag><tag>3</tag></sometag>';
    xml=$.parseXML(xml);
    $(xml).find("tag").each(function(index,value){
         if(value==3){
           //do wh ever you like
              }else{
           continue;
            }
      });
```